# Why the powershell script is not invoke inside my powershell program

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Hi i am quite frustrated with powershell. i want to use my powershell script to call another powershell script inside it.

My powershell only do the first part which is download files and does not invoke the following powershell script...

Can not think the reason behind it.. Could anyone help me with that? Thanks!

The Program looks like :

```
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path

Set-Location $directorypath

if ($StepNumber -ne 2) {
        $MyName = $MyInvocation.InvocationName
        $LogFileName = ".\Logs\" + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyName) + [String]::Format("_{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.Log", (Get-Date))
        if (!(Test-Path ".\Logs")) { 
            $X = New-Item -path . -name Logs -ItemType directory 
        }
&PowerShell.exe -noProfile -File NSCCMPIDDownload.ps1  2 *>`&1  | Tee $LogFileName
        exit
        }


## ## ---- STEP2 ------------DownLoad the file from Website


$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue" 


Write-Host Running NSCC-MPID-Download at $(Get-Date)
Write-Host ""

## Download the NSCC-MPID-Directory.xls from website

$datestr=$(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$url="http://www.dtcc.com/~/media/Files/Downloads/client-center/NSCC/NSCC-MPID-Directory.xls"
$destination = $directorypath +"/NSCC-MPID-Directory"+"_"+$datestr+".xls"

## if destination does not exsist, creat a new one.
if (!(Test-Path $destination) ) {
    New-Item $destination  -type file -force
}

$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$client.DownloadFile( $url, $destination)


Write-Host Running NSCCMPIDInsertion.ps1

$cmd = "$directorypath\NSCCMPIDInsertion.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "$cmd"


Write-Host Running NSCCMPIDAfterParse.ps1

$cmd = "$directorypath\NSCCMPIDAfterParse.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "$cmd"

Write-Host --------------------------------------------------------------------------
Write-Host Process ended at $(Get-Date)
```

Comment: Is it not hitting the `exit`, and well, exiting?

Comment: what do you mean not hitting exit? should i add exit at the end of the program?

Comment: @GarethLyons worded his question oddly. :) From the code it looks like it would get to the Exit statement then exit the script.

Comment: oh, thanks. but i have write host, it did not even hitting the 
Write-Host Running NSCCMPIDInsertion.ps1
 .....

Comment: Yeah, was wondering if the exit was causing the script to terminate, although I think it's actually terminating the powershell.exe session triggered in the line above.

Comment: you are right! it works when i delete the log powershell script,

Comment: But do you know what does this line of code do?&PowerShell.exe -noProfile -File NSCCMPIDDownload.ps1  2 *>`&1  | Tee $LogFileName
        exit

Comment: `&PowerShell.exe -noProfile -File NSCCMPIDDownload.ps1` invokes another instance of powershell.exe and runs the script file `NSCCMPIDDownload.ps1` in it. `2 *>\`&1` redirects the error output to the standard output so that they're combined. `Tee $LogFileName` outputs the combined stream both to the host and the file defined by `$LogFileName`. The `exit` I think is supposed to close this extra instance of powershell.exe but might instead be terminating your script, I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, got it. thanks so much Gareth.